# PC turns off when IntelliJ indexes

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a project with Kotlin and Spring Boot in IntelliJ IDEA. I never had any problem until yesterday when my PC started literally turning off randomly when IntelliJ was indexing. I have a PC with 12GB of RAM and a lot of space on disk and so memory shouldn't be a problem.

In the logs this showed up:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted /home/francesco/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/caches/names.dat  at com.intellij.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:132)  at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSConnection.handleError(PersistentFSConnection.java:299)  at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.handleError(FSRecords.java:723)

I deleted the cache (folder cache under `cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/caches`), but the problem is persisting. Reinstalled IntelliJ but the problem is still there.

Now this shows up in the logs that seem related:

> 2022-01-12 12:39:43,771 [ 210098]   INFO - sistent.PersistentFSConnection - Creating VFS corruption marker; Trace=
> java.lang.Exception at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSConnection.createBrokenMarkerFile(PersistentFSConnection.java:143)

After cache invalidation:

> 2022-01-12 12:29:25,474 [   2639]   INFO - rsistent.PersistentFSConnector - Filesystem storage is corrupted or does not exist. [Re]Building. Reason: FS repository version mismatch: actual=-1 expected=52027
> 2022-01-12 12:29:25,513 [   2678]   INFO - rsistent.PersistentFSConnector - Marking VFS as corrupted: .cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/caches/names.dat' does not exist

Does someone has any leads?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ?  I've never had that happen, and I've used the product every day for 17 years.  I'd contact JetBrains.  I wouldn't consider 12GB of RAM a lot of memory.

Comment: the last one 2021.3.1

Comment: Contact JetBrains.  That's your best bet.  Paid or community edition?

Comment: community edition.thanks.Can i do that without subscription?

Comment: Of course.  Worth it to pay.  Contact JetBrains.  At least send them the error.  You can't expect much support based on your billing history.

Comment: Try deleting the cache directory mentioned in the error.

Comment: Could the indexing be triggering a hardware issue, e.g. if it causes your CPU to overheat?

Comment: Are there any errors in system logs?

Answer (score 0):

it came out it was an hardware problem,did a mem test three times(maybe more) and each time pc turned off.Thank you for the support.